# table javascript pagination and sorting

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, search, html-table

How Can I search and paginate Table? Also, how to sort all cols *ascending* and *descending*? Now I can do it only in one way. 
Table loads data from javascript.

```js
const users = [
    {
      obec: 'Bratislava',
      okres: 'Bratislava',
      kraj: 'Bratislavský',
      obyvatelov: 411228,
      celkovo: 1,
      eco: 1,
      peo: 1,
      gov: 131,
      mob: 203,
      env: 81,
      liv: 3  }];

    //LOAD DATA
    let data = users.map(createRow);
    $('tbody').html(data);

    // SORT TABLE
    $('table thead td').on('click', e => {
      let $this = $(e.currentTarget);

      // Hide / show caret
      $('.fa-caret-down').hide();
      $this.find('.fa-caret-down').show();

      // Get type and sort data
      let type = e.target.id;
      let sorted = sort(users, type);

      // Create rows and set table HTML
      let data = sorted.map(createRow);
      $('tbody').html(data);
    });

    function createRow(user) {
      let row = `<tr>
                  <td>${user.obec}</td>
                  <td>${user.okres}</td>
                  <td>${user.kraj}</td>
         <td>${user.obyvatelov}</td>
         <td>${user.celkovo}</td>
         <td>${user.eco}</td>
         <td>${user.peo}</td>
         <td>${user.gov}</td>
         <td>${user.mob}</td>
         <td>${user.env}</td>
         <td>${user.liv}</td>
                 </tr>`;
      return row;
    }

    function sort(obj, type) {
      let sorted = obj.sort((b, a) => 
      type === 'obyvatelov' ? b.obyvatelov - a.obyvatelov :
      type === 'celkovo' ? b.celkovo - a.celkovo :
      type === 'eco' ? b.eco - a.eco :
      type === 'peo' ? b.peo - a.peo :
      type === 'gov' ? b.gov - a.gov :
      type === 'mob' ? b.mob - a.mob :
      type === 'env' ? b.env - a.env :
      type === 'liv' ? b.liv - a.liv :
      a.obec.localeCompare(b.obec));

      return sorted;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
         <thead>
         <tr>
          <td id="obec">Obec <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
          <td id="okres">Okres</td>
          <td id="kraj">Kraj</td>
          <td id="obyvatelov">Počet obyvateľov <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
          <td id="celkovo">Celkové poradie<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
          <td id="eco">Economy <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
          <td id="peo">People <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
          <td id="gov">Governance <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
          <td id="mob">Mobility <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
          <td id="env">Environment <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
          <td id="liv">Living <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- partial -->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script src="new.js"></script>
```

I am new in javascript and can not solve this. I red whole internet but no luck.

[image: What I want to achieve]

This is how I want to look it like.

Comment: have u look [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Paginate-Sort-Filter-Table-Sortable.html)

Comment: consider using https://datatables.net/